# MVC 3, IIS 8.5 deployment = 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have an existing deployed ASP.NET MVC3 application using Entity Framework 4.1 and .NET 4 that I need to copy onto a new server. Problem is I have little or no documentation about how the deployed environment was configured. On the up side I do administrator access to the deployment environment and full access to the source code to the application.

So starting from bare metal I have:

- Fresh install of Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2014 Enterprise
- Installed MVC 3 and Tools via Web Platform Installer

[image]

- Copied entire website from existing deployment to its own folder under C:\inetpub
- Added website under IIS and started it with the App Pool configured as

[image]

- Browse to website and it returns the default.htm page in the root folder. This is not expected behaviour as it should serve up the default controller view.
- Check to see that I can access a html file elsewhere within the website eg. http://myhost.com:443/SomeDir/test.htm and it serves that up
- See if it will hit a route I know exists eg. http://myhost.com:443/Auth/NewLogin and I get

[image]

- Various readings indicate that occasionally this is caused by "UrlRoutingModule-4.0" not being installed in modules. It wasn't so I added same server wide and ensure it was present for the website (Made no difference):

[image]

- There is also mention of ensuring **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"** was present in the web.config which it is

**UPDATE**

.NET is installed:

[image]

So before I post a "Failed Request Trace" can anyone give me any suggestions on how I proceed to get MVC working in this environment?

I have read may SO posts and Googled but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I once spent a good while debugging a similar problem only to find out that somebody had forgotten to install ASP.NET to begin with. Did you check that it's installed properly? Easiest way to check is to see if you have an "ASP.NET" category in the IIS manager when you click on the site.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Double checked that .NET is installed

Comment: Did you assign the app pool identity to the anonymous user?  Go to Authentication, right client on Anonymous, select App Pool Identity.

Comment: if ASP.NET was installed before IIS, try to run: aspnet_regiis -i

Comment: @ErikOppedijk Is that the equivalent of selecting .NET 4.51 under Application Programming when adding IIS in the Roles and Features in server manager?

Comment: I think it is the same, check it with a simple aspx page to make sure asp.net is working before checking mvc.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, when the system was configired someone did not configure IIS to use .NET. See my comment on Dec 11 as to what I did

Comment: @TheEdge, i'm facing the same issue, did you solve this issue? I was supposed to configure a demo application, but am badly stuck now. It works fine in IIS 7.5 with Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Yes I did. Read my comment above yours... Either run aspnet_regiis.... or using the GUI via the server roles manager.

Comment: @TheEdge can we take this to chat? I've got a few questions. Name of room is 'IIS 8.5'.